# DataGridView causes "Program Not Responding" when data displayed fills view and vertical scrollbar appears

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, datagridview

I am working in Visual Studio 2010 .NET 4.0 in C# using WinForms.

The form has a single `DataGridView` that is data bound to a `DataSet`.

The `DataSet` is being populated from a `Thread` that is processing data being read from a `ConcurrentQueue`.

The code is also using a semaphore to serialize access to the `DataSet` as it can be accessed from the "worker" Thread and the UI main thread ( when updating the `DataGridView` ).

The UI/Form has a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` that fires every 1/4 second to call a function that causes the `DataGridView` to be updated with the current contents of the `DataSet`.

The code runs correctly until the point at which the `DataGridView` data scrolls and the scroll bar becomes visible. At this point the entire form becomes unresponsive - title caption says "Program Not Responding".

The interesting thing is that this DOESN'T happen while running under the debugger. Only when the program is deployed. And no exceptions are ever raised.

I've tried using both Invoke and BeginInvoke with no change in behavior.

Questions:

1- What might be wrong with my code below?  
2- Since I can't observe this behavior while running under the debugger, how do I find out what is causing the problem?

The wall of code is provided below. I know it's a lot of code, but I cut out as much as I could.

```
// deleted using statements for brevity

namespace namcom
{
    public partial class wndXMLtrans : Form
    {
        private DataSet dsRecords = new DataSet();
        private Thread threadConsumeXML = null;
        private static Semaphore ResourceLock;

        public wndXMLtrans(String ip)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ResourceLock = new Semaphore(1, 1);
            curSize = this.Size;
            m_ip = ip;
        }

        private Boolean AddRowToDataSet(String[] columns, String xml)
        {
            Boolean retCode = true;
            String value = String.Empty;
            Int64 id = -1;
            DataRow row;

            ResourceLock.WaitOne();
            row = dsRecords.Tables[0].NewRow();

            // prepare row code omitted - brevity

            // add new data row to DataSet
            dsRecords.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
            ResourceLock.Release();
            // SQL inserts into DB removed - brevity
            return (retCode);
        }

        private Boolean HandleSingleXMLMessage(String[] columns, String xml, out String exceptionMessage)
        {
            Boolean boolRet = true;
            exceptionMessage = String.Empty;

            // store data in dataset and database
            if ( closeRequested == false  )
            {
                AddRowToDataSet(columns, xml);
            }
            return (boolRet);
        }

        private Boolean StoreG2SMessages(String message)
        {
            // code removed - brevity
            // removed code just parses out string and in a loop calls HandleSingleXMLMessage
            // until all XML in message have been processed
            HandleSingleXMLMessage(columns,xml, out exceptionMessage)  // call in loop
            return (ret);
        }

        // pull XML out of mainwnd.msgQueue and update database
        private void G2SParseThread()
        {
            String Data;
            String exceptionMsg = String.Empty;

            while ( /* thread is to be active - code removed for brevity */)
            {
                Data = String.Empty;
                if (mainwnd.msgQueue.TryDequeue(out Data) == true)
                {
                    this.StoreG2SMessages(Data);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
            // thread ended cleanup code removed - brevity
        }


        private void StartThreads()
        {
            // start XML packet processing thread
            threadConsumeXML = new Thread(G2SParseThread);
            threadConsumeXML.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            threadConsumeXML.Start();

            threadMonitor = new Thread(() => threadHandleStatusMsg(ref mainwnd.statusQueue));
            threadMonitor.Start();
        }


        private void wndXMLtrans_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // remove SQL code - brevity
            // fill dsRecords ( DataSet )
            try
            {
                var adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(selectSQL, dbConnection);
                adapter.Fill(dsRecords);
                dataGrid.DataSource = dsRecords.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                adapter.Dispose();
            }
            catch { } // catch code removed - brevity
            StartThreads();
        }

        private void gridUpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ResourceLock.WaitOne();
            try
            {
                if (dataGrid != null && numRows < dsRecords.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
                {
                    if (dataGrid.RowCount > 0)
                    {
                        dataGrid.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGrid.RowCount - 1;
                    }
                    dataGrid.Refresh();
                    numRows = dsRecords.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                }
            }
            catch { }
            ResourceLock.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Hans provided the answer which is that you can't update a bound `DataSet` from a worker thread. So I was able to fix the problem by adding the following:

These are called by delegate functions using Invoke. Unbind called before `DataSet` update and Bind after `DataSet` is updated. This works, but causes the `DataGridView` to appear to flicker or redraw multiple times. Any way to remedy this?

```
public void UnbindDataGridView(DataGridView grid)
{
    grid.DataSource = null;
}

public void BindDataGridView(DataGridView grid)
{
    grid.DataSource = dsRecords.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

Comment: You cannot update a bound dataset from a worker thread.  You will have to unbind it first.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the tip. I've made a change that unbinds the DataGridView before the call to `StoreG2SMessage` and when `StoreG2SMessage` return I then rebind the `DataGridView`. This fixes the program, however now it looks like the `DataGridView` is being redrawn twice for every update ( when new data is added ). Any idea how to fix that? Thanks again.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".