# Unbinding dataGridView before updating a datatable on a worker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, datatable

I have a problem very similar to the issue raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165159/datagridview-causes-program-not-responding-when-data-displayed-fills-view-and). I have data streaming in from a serial port. The serial received event updates a data table (public property in the same class). When data are received on the port, I unbind a dataGridView; update the data table by adding a row; then update the dataGridView using a delagate. All works fine while debugging (or creating a release within VS2010). However, if I run the program from the creation directory (debug or release) or install, when the dataGridView gets to a number of rows requiring a scroll, the program locks up and times out? It doesn't happen when running from within VS2010 - but does "outside" the development environment???

I'm trying to update the dataGridView using the event raised from `dataRowChanged`.

Here is the code:

```
    void dtData_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        SetGridView(dataGridView1);
    }
```

And the delegate:

```
delegate void SetGridViewCallBack(DataGridView dgv);
private void SetGridView(DataGridView dgv)
{
    // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
    // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    // If these threads are different, it returns true.
    if (this.dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetGridViewCallBack d = new SetGridViewCallBack(SetGridView);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { dgv });
    }
    else
    {
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dtData;
        this.dataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
        this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
        this.dataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
        this.dataGridView1.Refresh();

        // if scolled, focus on the last row
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 3)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1];
        }
    }
```

OK - so a) why would this crash "outside" the IDE??? and b) what am I doing wrong???

Thanks in advance for any help